# QGIS Naming in Legend Based on Multiple Columns

Tags: qgis, symbology

Is it possible to have the symbol name in QGIS based on two different columns in the attribute table.
I have this right now and I want all the entries to be like the first A. I could manually type them in but I have over 120 entries. Is there a way with an expression to do this for every entry?

[image: Symbology Naming]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just press Style in the properties tab on the left, then switch to Categorized at the top then press the 'E' expression button near the Column pull-down menu.

Enter an expression based on your need with any columns, then press OK.

[image: setting up expression for categories from multiple attributes in qgis]

Finally press Classify and they should populate then press OK to return to the canvas to see them.

[image: applying the multi-attribute expression in qgis]

An example:
[image: visualizing an example of categories in qgis from multiple attributes]

Comment: That is a very nice (and colourful!) example :)

Comment: Thanks, that works great! Just wondering if someone could explain the double bar operator is used for exactly? I have never used it before and not sure what the symbol does in an expression. Maybe with some examples?

Comment: @Aurust The || is a concatenate operator, similar to " + " with a string in Python or " & " in VB. It puts the strings on either side of it together to form a single longer string. In the example consider subzone "dh" and subzone name "Dry Hot". Think of it as: "dh" || ' - ' || "Dry Hot".  Here, "dh" and " - " become "dh - ", and then "Dry Hot" is added to get "dh - Dry Hot".